# Nested comment system runs too many queries ( laravel & livewire )

Tags: php, laravel

I've built a nested comment system and it works fine, but I have a problem.
when I want to show the comments, it runs too many queries. for example if I have 10 comments and two replies each, laravel debugger shows 40+ queries, and I want to reduce them, here is my code :

**Query**

```
$comments = $post->mentions()->with(['author', 'reply'])->get();
```

**Relationship in Post.php Model**

```
public function mentions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'post_id')->where('approved',1)->where('parent_id',0);
    }
```

**Comments Relationships**

```
 public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id')->select('id', 'name', 'avatar', 'role');
    }

    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id')->where('approved', 1);
    }
```

**Blade File**

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <div x-data="{reply:false}" class="break-words bg-white border-2 rounded-lg p-4 my-5" id="answer-{1}">
        <div wire:ignore class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <img class="rounded-full w-20 border-4 @if ($comment->author->role == 'administrator') border-blue-500 @else border-gray-500 @endif " src="{{ $comment->author->avatar }}"
                    alt="{{ $comment->author->name }}">
                <div>
                    <div class="flex pr-3">
                        <a href="/@username"
                            class="font-bold text-lg text-gray-800 hover:text-gray-900">{{ $comment->author->name }}</a>
                        @if ($comment->author->role == 'administrator')
                            <img class="w-5 mr-1" src="/img/verified.svg" alt="" title="admin">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <p class="font-light cursor-default text-gray-700 pt-1 pr-3">
                        {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg @click="reply = true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 cursor-pointer hover:text-rose-600"
                fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                    d="M3 10h10a8 8 0 018 8v2M3 10l6 6m-6-6l6-6" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="comment_body leading-8 pt-3 text-gray-800 cursor-default">
            <div wire:ignore>
                {!! nl2br($comment->body) !!}
            </div>
            <div x-cloak x-show="reply">
                <form class="py-3" wire:submit.prevent="SubmitComment({{ $comment->id }})">
                    <textarea wire:model.defer="commentBody"
                        class="w-full focus:ring-0 bg-zinc-200 border shadow focus:bg-zinc-100 mt-3 p-4 rounded-lg"
                        id="editor" rows="6" placeholder=""></textarea>
                    @error('commentBody') <p class="text-red-600 mt-1 text-sm">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="flex mt-3">
                        <div @click="reply = false"
                            class="bg-red-600 rounded-lg ml-3 text-white px-3 py-2 cursor-pointer">
                            Cancel
                        </div>
                        <button wire:loading.remove wire:target="SubmitComment" type="submit"
                            class="inline-block bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900  transition duration-300 px-3 py-2  text-white rounded-md">
                            Send
                        </button>
                        <button wire:loading="" wire:target="SubmitComment" type="button"
                            class="flex bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900  transition duration-300 px-3 py-2  text-white rounded-md"
                            disabled>
                            <span class="flex justify-center">
                                <svg class="animate-spin w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor"
                                        stroke-width="4"></circle>
                                    <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 3.042 1.135 5.824 3 7.938l3-2.647z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
                @include('partials.comment',['comments'=>$comment->reply])
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot seperator to get the nested relationship

```
$comments = $post->with(['mentions.author','mentions.reply'])
   ->first()
   ->mentions;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it reduced the queries, but I tested it with around 1000 comments and random replies, now I have 30 queries but the model tab in laravel debugger shows around 1200 models in use, can I optimize this too?

Comment: yes because eager load will load all comments in the memory, if you're using lazy load it will not load all comments in memory but run many queries, the solutions for this is to paginate the comments instead.